# GJS Notification - no notification shown

Tags: notifications, gio, gjs

I am working on one project, that will create notification from gjs script.
There is no error, but notification is not shown.
Any suggestion?
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/gjs
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
var Application = new Gio.Application({applicationId:"sk.project.app", flags:32});
var Notification = new Gio.Notification();
Notification.set_body("message here");
Application.send_notification(null, Notification);
```

Answer (score 3):

In order for a GNotification to be shown, you must have an associated `.desktop` file in either `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/`.

This file should have the `X-GNOME-UsesNotifications` key, and by convention would be named `sk.project.app.desktop`.

If sent without an icon set, the desktop will use the application icon defined in that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Application
Exec=/path/to/myapp.js
Terminal=false
Icon=sk.project.app
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
```